# Pattern Match on all words not just whole

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do wild card matching on a linq statement but its not working as suspected.

```
_supplierItems.Where(w =>  
w.description.ToLower().Contains(txtProductCode.Text))
                       .Select(s=>s.code).FirstOrDefault();
cboSupplier.DataSource = _supplierItems;
cboSupplier.DisplayMember = "description";
cboSupplier.ValueMember = "code";
cboSupplier.Enabled = true;
```

For Example if the name Christian Seltmann and the person types lower case S or whatever it should find that and populate the combo items, my question is is Contains the correct way of doing this.

I also tried the following

```
_supplierItems.Where(w => 
 w.description.ToLower().Contains(txtProductCode.Text)).Select(s => 
s.code).ToList()
```

But it cannot convert string to list can someone point me out as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
_supplierItems.Where(w => w.description.ToLower().Contains(txtProductCode.Text.ToLower()))
   .Select(s => s.code)
   .ToList()
```

or you can create own extension method like

```
public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string cont)
{
    return source.IndexOf(cont, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

and use it

```
_supplierItems.Where(w => w.description.ContainsIgnoreCase(txtProductCode.Text))
   .Select(s => s.code)
   .ToList()
```

Comment: thats a nice extension method but its complaining about the char incomptable is that cause Text not treated as a char

Answer (score 0):

That code looks about right except for the fact that you're not doing anything with the return value of your Linq call. Try

```
var result = _supplierItems.Where(w => w.description.ToLower().Contains(txtProductCode.Text)).Select(s=>s.code).FirstOrDefault();
cboSupplier.DataSource = result;
```

You will need this code in your change handler for the txtProductCode control.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, first defect is that you are ignoring the result of LINQ query. LINQ does not mutate the data source, it produces a new data stream if you use something like `ToXxx()` (`ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `ToDictionary()` etc.) or iterates over the result of `Select()` or `Where()`.

Second issue is that you are only databinding first record which matches.

```
cboSupplier.DataSource = _supplierItems.Where(w =>  
w.description.ToLower().Contains(txtProductCode.Text))
                       .Select(s=>s.code);
```

This will search all matching items.